# Can't get a correct signature of Entringer number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

I am stuck with understanding [Entringer numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EntringerNumber.html) which:

> E(n,k) are the number of permutations of {1,2,...,n+1}, starting with
>   k+1, which, after initially falling, alternately fall then rise.

which looks like a partial case of a [permutation with a given signature](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607763.pdf) (page 2 for a small table with examples and page 10 for a recurrence formula).

So now I am trying to calculate `E(n, k)` as a number of signatures. Taking the example `E(7, 3)`.

It is equal to `178` according to the Entringer numbers recursion formula. Now when I construct a signature, which in my opinion is `----+-+` (3 times falling and than fall, rise, fall rise).

But `F(----+-+) = 105` (F is the number of permutations with the signature). I tried a couple of other signatures, but still can not get the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood the definition of the Entringer numbers. $E(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of $[n+1]$ that begin with $k+1$ and have an alternating signature of length $n$ that begins with a `-`. Thus, the four permutations counted by $E(4,2)=4$ are $32415$, $32514$, $31425$, and $31524$, all with signature `-+-+`.

Comment: Oh, so $E(16, 5)$ would be the number of the alternative permutations where the first number is 6. Am I right?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Yes, exactly: the number of alternating permutations of $[17]$ with first number $6$.

Comment: Thank you for a clarification. I knew that I somehow misinterpreted the definition.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: You’re welcome.